# Insert data from a 50 GB table to another 100GB table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-7

I need to insert data from a 50 GB table `table1` to another 100GB table `table2` in the same database. `table1`'s columns are all `varchar(50)`, and `table2`'s columns are `int` and `float`.

```
table1: non clustered primary key

   id1  id2  value            -- all types are varchar(50)
   242 8965   8974202.87412

table2: id1  id2  are clustered primary key

   id1  id2  value            -- id1 and id2 types are int, value is float
   257 872   9826531.889
```

My code:

```
INSERT INTO [my_db].[dbo].[table2] 
SELECT Cast(a.id1 AS INT), 
       Cast(a.id2 AS INT), 
       Cast(a.value AS FLOAT) 
FROM   [my_db].[dbo].[table1] AS a
```

Will the inserted data in `table2` be the same as in `table1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that use SSIS in order to convert data in order to have better performance.

If you don't want to use SSIS I suggest that drop all indexes and foreign key and constraint and trigger before start your convert and then create them.

Also before start convert check duplicate record in table1 and then use following query to save data from table1 into table2:

```
INSERT INTO [my_db].[dbo].[table2]
SELECT cast(a.id1 AS INT), cast(a.id2 AS INT), cast(a.value as float) 
FROM [my_db].[dbo].[table1] as a
LEFT JOIN [my_db].[dbo].[table2] AS b ON b.id1 = a.id1
                                        AND b.id2 = a.id2
WHERE b.id1 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

you must check table1 have duplicate key id1,id2 when insert to table2 if it duplicate insert fail